# Unity Addressables | Добавить в List позиции всех ассетов без загрузки в оперативную память

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, нужно создать список позиций Addressable ассетов из группы, чтобы позже грузить их в реальном времени при приближении, но я не могу полностью грузить их в память, т.к вся карта занимает 2гб, что недопустимо на мобильных, сейчас не смотря на то, что загружаю и выгружаю по отдельности, в память грузятся все

```
public class AddressableTestRuntimeLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<AssetReference> _mapAssets = new();
    [SerializeField] private List<Vector3> _mapAssetsPositions = new();

    public IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var loadAssetLocationsOperation = Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync("map");

        yield return loadAssetLocationsOperation;

        foreach (IResourceLocation location in loadAssetLocationsOperation.Result)
        {
            AssetReference assetReference = new(location.PrimaryKey.ToString());
            _mapAssets.Add(assetReference);

            var instantiateAsset = assetReference.InstantiateAsync();

            yield return instantiateAsset;

            _mapAssetsPositions.Add(instantiateAsset.Result.transform.position);
            Addressables.Release(instantiateAsset);
        }
    }
}
```